# forEach Loop failing on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, screen

I'm trying to build a website using react native for routing between pages, although when i set up the Stack i keep getting this error.

[The error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOdCu.png)
Here is my App.tsx page

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
// eslint-disable-next-line
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

// import Screens

import './App.css';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import LoginScreen from './screens/login/login.screen';
import FrontScreen from './screens/front.screen';
import { BackScreen } from './screens/back.screen';
import { RootStackParamList } from './screens/RootStackPrams';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();


const App = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<string>('Login');

  console.log(Stack);
  console.log(LoginScreen);
  console.log(currentPage);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name = "Login" component = {LoginScreen}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = "Front" component={FrontScreen}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

    );
};

export default App;
```

My root stack params

```
// screens/RootStackPrams.ts
export type RootStackParamList = {
    Front: undefined;
    Login: undefined;
    };
```

And my page that is being implemented

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {StackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../RootStackPrams';
type loginScreenProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Login'>;

function LoginScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation<loginScreenProp>();

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Auth Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Front" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Front')} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

I have followed two different tutorials with two completley different implementations but both result the same

I have tried multiple different approaches, if i get rid of the Stack.Screens then the error is as expected asking where the screens are.

Comment: The error i am getting:

Comment: Where is the `forEach` in your code? The error means that the array that you're trying to apply the `forEach` method is undefined.

Comment: It was in the react native code, turns out its a problem with their newest version a downgrade fixed it!

Comment: happy to hear you fixed it!